# Host dynamic iCal on GAE Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, icalendar

I'm planning for an app that keeps a database of events. Users could query for events they're interested in (based on geography, tags, etc.) and obtain a link to a dynamic iCal to sync with their personal calendar. When new events are added to the database that match their query, their calendar will be updated.

This should be hosted on GAE using python. I've already found a Python module that should be able to render the content for the iCal: [icalendar](https://github.com/collective/icalendar/).

Now my question: how to setup the web server aspect? I understand that iCal is not going over http, but over webdav protocol, but on the other hand, webdav is an extension of http with extra features for write operations to the server, and I don't need that for my read-only calendar, do I?

Question 1: can I just host my iCal over http://, using webapp2 with the proper mime type and nothing more? Or will (some) clients not accept this?

Question 2: if I need to have webdav:// protocol, where do I start? There are modules around that do webdav, but they're more like fileservers (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/gae-webdav/) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/gaedav/), looks like they're not maintained anymore either), and that's totally not what I need. Can webapp2 or another mainstream python web framework help me for my read-only iCal? Webapp2 help doesn't say a word about webdav...

Thanks for any advice you can give!

Vic

Comment: have you found any solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a simple version of iCalendar server on top of BaseHTTPRequestHandler. Same idea can be used with GAE. More complex content renderer such as [icalendar](https://github.com/collective/icalendar/) can be used:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

PORT = 8000
DESC = "The long desciption of event. I've tried to keep it serious but at some point"


def limit_to_75_octets(inp):
    if len(inp) <= 73:
        return inp + "\r\n"

    out = ""
    while len(inp) > 73:
        out += inp[:73] + "\r\n"
        inp = " " + inp[73:]

    if len(inp) == 0:
        return out
    else:
        return out + inp + "\r\n"

def render_alarm():
    """creates an alarm 10 minutes before event start"""

    return ("BEGIN:VALARM\r\n" +
        "TRIGGER:-PT10M\r\n" +
        "ACTION:DISPLAY\r\n" +
        limit_to_75_octets("DESCRIPTION:Reminder: %s" % DESC) +
        "END:VALARM\r\n")

def render_event():
    """create and event
    uid: unique event id
    dtstamp: time when event was created
    dtstart: event start time
    dtend: event end time (all dates are in utc)
    """

    return ("BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n" +
        "UID:uid1@example.com\r\n" +
        "DTSTAMP:20141107T200200Z\r\n" +
        "DTSTART:20141109T153000Z\r\n" +
        "DTEND:20141109T163000Z\r\n" +
        limit_to_75_octets("SUMMARY:%s" % DESC) +
        render_alarm() +
        "END:VEVENT\r\n")

def render_calendar():
    return ("BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n" +
        "VERSION:2.0\r\n" +
        "PRODID:-//Example Corp.//CalDAV Server//EN\r\n" +
        render_event() +
        "END:VCALENDAR\r\n")


class SharedCalendarServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/calendar")
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write(render_calendar())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(("", PORT), SharedCalendarServer)
        print "Server running on", PORT
        server.serve_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Shutting down the web server."
        server.socket.close()
```